# Error connecting to docker daemon from a docker run in Bitbucket Pipelines script

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

In bitbucket pipeline, I have added a step to run docker-bench-security.

```
step:
          name: Docker Bench Security
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
          script:
            - docker run -e DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=$DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --label docker_bench_security docker/docker-bench-security -e check_1.*
```

The pipeline execution fails with below error.

```
Error connecting to docker daemon (does docker ps work?)
```

Could anyone please help me to fix it?

Comment: Please fix the title of your question so it is related to the actual issue. It is not about "docker bench security" but about "Error connecting to docker daemon from a docker run in Bitbucket Pipelines script"

Answer (score 0):

In Bitbucket Pipelines you don't have an actual `/var/run/docker.sock` to connect. Imitating how Bitbucket forwards the docker engine to docker pipes, the actual options should be something like

```
docker run
  --env=DOCKER_HOST="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375"
  --volume=/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker:ro
  --add-host="host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL"
  ...
```